# SFML and VS. The program runs with no errors in VS environment, but when the .exe file is tried to run - it opens and immediately closes

Tags: c++17, exe, sfml

I have build the project in both debug and release modes for x64 bit platforms.
I have VS 2022 version, and SFML 2.6.0 version: Visual C++ 17 (2022) - 64-bit.
The program works as excpected in VS, no errors.
When I try to run the .exe file from Release folder, it opens for a moment and instantly closes.
This is my Release folder contents:
[Release folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6omGX.png)

I tried to look for the reason of the crush in log files. It says I have encountered error event with id 1000, and exception code: 0xc0000005.

Comment: Are you using any data files? If you run the program through VS the working directory is different than if you just run the `.exe` by itself.

Comment: I added some .txt files and .ttf files for the font in the Release folder, which worked! Thank you very much